# When using "Type 4" print driver print jobs are faint

Tags: hp, network-printer

Bit of a strange one; when printing to a networked HP LaserJet 500 MFP M525 using a "Type 4" printer driver the print jobs are faint (ie black text comes out dark grey).

If I download and install a "Type 3" Universal Print driver from the HP website print jobs are printing normally (ie black text comes out black).

I've tested this on both Windows 2012 R2 and Windows 10 clients, and from different applications and the output is the same. I've also tried updating the firmware to the latest version to no avail.

How do I stop the print jobs from being faint with the "Type 4" drivers?

Comment: What is your question?  Please edit your post to include one.

Comment: How do I stop print jobs using the Type 4 driver from being faint?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a question.  Not everyone reads comments in order to figure out what you're asking.